# Why Flume takes more resource (%CPU) when File is used as channel , compared to when memory is used as channel.?

Tags: bigdata, apache-kafka, apache-storm, flume

I am trying to use File as channel since it is reliable in case an agent gets crashed, compared to using memory as channel.
What i see is %CPU in case of File channel is like 99 - 110 % , whereas %CPU in case of memory channel is 10-17 % only,
Can somebody explain the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems normal, disk seeking is slower than pointing to a memory address. And per-byte copying will be slower as well.